# I have a datagrid view which saves data in the database but the delete and update not working

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, datagridview

I have a form with datagrid view and three buttons, AddNew, Save, Remove

When i click on the AddNew Button a new row gets added, the code used for that is:

```
 this.netWeightMasterDataBindingSource.AddNew();
```

so turn out that the datatableadapter has properties that does the delete, insert and update so i decided to go that route:

Insert Button

```
this.net_Weight_Master_DataTableAdapter.Insert(this.corsicanaNetWeightDataSet.Net_Weight_Master_Data);
                net_Weight_Master_DataDataGridView.Refresh();
MessageBox.Show("Record Inserted");
```

Delete Button

```
   //Update button update dataset after insertion,upadtion or deletion
            DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure to delete the record", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                this.net_Weight_Master_DataTableAdapter.Delete(this.corsicanaNetWeightDataSet.Net_Weight_Master_Data);
                net_Weight_Master_DataDataGridView.Refresh();
                MessageBox.Show("Record Deleted");
            }
            if (dr == DialogResult.No)
            {
                Close();
            }
```

**Delete Sql**

```
         DELETE FROM [dbo].[Net Weight Master Data] 
        WHERE (([Unit UPC Base Item] = @Original_Unit_UPC_Base_Item) 
       AND ([Production Line] = @Original_Production_Line) 
       AND ((@IsNull_Preset_Number = 1 AND [Preset Number] IS NULL) 
       OR ([Preset Number] = @Original_Preset_Number)) 
       AND ((@IsNull_Package_Type = 1 
      AND [Package Type] IS NULL) OR ([Package Type] = @Original_Package_Type)) 
      AND ((@IsNull_Weight_Factor = 1 
      AND [Weight Factor] IS NULL) OR ([Weight Factor] = @Original_Weight_Factor))  AND ((@IsNull_Piece = 1 AND [Piece] IS NULL) OR ([Piece] = @Original_Piece)) 
    AND ((@IsNull_Units_Per_Carton = 1 AND [Units Per Carton] IS NULL) OR ([Units Per Carton] = @Original_Units_Per_Carton)) 
    AND ((@IsNull_Pcs_Per_Unit = 1 AND [Pcs Per Unit] IS NULL) OR ([Pcs Per Unit] = @Original_Pcs_Per_Unit)) 
    AND ((@IsNull_Upper_Limit_Unit = 1 AND [Upper Limit Unit] IS NULL) OR ([Upper Limit Unit] = @Original_Upper_Limit_Unit)) 
    AND ((@IsNull_Upper_Limit_Factor = 1 AND [Upper Limit Factor] IS NULL) OR ([Upper Limit Factor] = @Original_Upper_Limit_Factor)) 
    AND ((@p3 = 1 AND [Label Wt (g)] IS NULL) OR ([Label Wt (g)] = @p2)) AND ((@p6 = 1 AND [Tare Wt (g)] IS NULL) OR ([Tare Wt (g)] = @p5)) AND ((@p9 = 1 
    AND [Constant Tare Wt (g)] IS NULL) OR ([Constant Tare Wt (g)] = @p8)) AND ((@p12 = 1 AND [Tare Variation Factor (g)] IS NULL) OR ([Tare Variation Factor (g)] = @p11)) 
    AND ((@p15 = 1 AND [Pkg Length (mm)] IS NULL) OR ([Pkg Length (mm)] = @p14)) AND ((@IsNull_Film_Product_Code = 1 
AND [Film Product Code] IS NULL) OR ([Film Product Code] = @Original_Film_Product_Code)) AND ((@p18 = 1 
AND [Film Width (mm)] IS NULL) OR ([Film Width (mm)] = @p17)) AND ((@p21 = 1 AND [Forming Tube (mm)] IS NULL) OR ([Forming Tube (mm)] = @p20)) AND ((@IsNull_Type_of_Jaws = 1 
AND [Type of Jaws] IS NULL) OR ([Type of Jaws] = @Original_Type_of_Jaws)) 
AND ((@IsNull_Last_Updated = 1 AND [Last Updated] IS NULL) OR ([Last Updated] = @Original_Last_Updated)) AND ((@IsNull_Comments = 1 AND [Comments] IS NULL) OR ([Comments] = @Original_Comments)) AND ((@IsNull_Field1 = 1 AND [Field1] IS NULL) OR ([Field1] = @Original_Field1)))
```

Update Button

```
 //Update button update dataset after insertion,upadtion or deletion
         DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure to save Changes", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
         if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            this.net_Weight_Master_DataTableAdapter.Update(this.corsicanaNetWeightDataSet.Net_Weight_Master_Data);
            net_Weight_Master_DataDataGridView.Refresh();
            MessageBox.Show("Record Updated");
        }
```

i am havig errors with the insert and delete button the error i get is more overload for methods takes 1 argument

Comment: when you click the remove and it's being removed from the grid.. where is the actual code that does the Delete.. as well as the call to rebind the datagrid..?

Comment: You Have to Update DataTableAdapter After removing the row, to reflect it on your grid like this  `this.netWeightMasterDataBindingSource.RemoveCurrent();
 this.netWeightMasterDataBindingSource.EndEdit();     this.net_Weight_Master_DataTableAdapter.Update(this.corsicanaNetWeightDataSet.Net_Weight_Master_Data);`

Comment: @MethodMan i added some more code in the question does that help?? plz help!!

Comment: @prasy i added some more code to the question plz help!!

Comment: your code additions need to be added to the original question.. edit your question and paste the code additions there

Comment: I am not sure why you are not showing what the Delete Sql looks like also I can think of 10 different ways to do this better.. but I have no time right now to demonstrate.. it's 4pm here which equates to `Miller Time`

Comment: @MethodMan :0 enjoy the Miller Time, i could have my Miller Time once i am done with this daunting issue :)

Comment: I would suggest to use plain ADO.NET or an ORM rather than using this approach.

Comment: @MethodMan added the Delete Sql to the question

Comment: personally I would totally re-factor this whole solution / approach and port all of that into a StoredProcedure.. then I would take advantage of the SQLCommand Class , SQLConnection Class etc.. this looks very messy and hard to manage.. have you thought about ways to optimize your query as well..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use an alternative approach and update the dataset after each action that refreshes the database.

To Insert a Record

```
this.Validate();
            this.netWeightMasterDataBindingSource.EndEdit();
            this.net_Weight_Master_DataTableAdapter.Update(this.corsicanaNetWeightDataSet.Net_Weight_Master_Data);
            //this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.corsicanaNetWeightDataSet);
            MessageBox.Show("Record Inserted");
```

To Delete a Record

```
   DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure to delete the record", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        this.netWeightMasterDataBindingSource.RemoveCurrent();
        this.netWeightMasterDataBindingSource.EndEdit();
        this.net_Weight_Master_DataTableAdapter.Update(this.corsicanaNetWeightDataSet.Net_Weight_Master_Data);
        net_Weight_Master_DataDataGridView.Refresh();
        MessageBox.Show("Record Deleted");
    }
    if (dr == DialogResult.No)
    {
        Close();
    }
```

To Update a Record

```
DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure to save Changes", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
         if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            this.net_Weight_Master_DataTableAdapter.Update(this.corsicanaNetWeightDataSet.Net_Weight_Master_Data);
            net_Weight_Master_DataDataGridView.Refresh();
            MessageBox.Show("Record Updated");
        }
```

Comment: It worked but the only thing is that if the user deletes, inserts and updated several rows at once and just clicks the update, insert or the delete button once all the changes will reflect on the database.I was thinking of doing the same as well. appreciate the help bud!!.